# Load External Files with C# (From Resource Folder)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a PDF file that I would like to load with a button click.  I can reference the file in debug mode, but when I publish the project, the pdf doesn't migrate over or 'install' with the project.

The file is located in `Resources/file.pdf`

In the WPF form, I call the "OpenFile_Click" function on click.

Here is my function:

```
private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
  string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
  Process.Start(appPath + "Resources/file.pdf");
}
```

This clearly doesn't work to open that file.  I can add `../../` in front of the Resources folder and it will open in debug, but that isn't very helpful.

So, what is the best option for opening an external file like a PDF?

Comment: What's the Build action of this file (in the solution explorer)?

Comment: In the file Properties (in the context menu in Solution Explorer), set Copy to Output Directory.

Answer (score 1):

After setting `Properties\Copy to Output Directory` = `Copy if Newer` as suggested by Clemens, I would also recommend the use of `System.IO.Path.Combine` to ensure the correct path delimiter for the platform.

If there is still an error when invoking the `Process.Start` then try starting "explorer.exe" with the combined file name. I successfully tested the following, see if you can repro.

```
private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "Resources",
        "file.pdf"
    );

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", filePath);
}
```